# Performance analysis of Sorting Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, benchmarking

I am trying to compare the performance of couple of sorting algorithms. Are there any existing benchmarks that can make my task easy? If not I want create my own benchmark. How would I achieve this?
Couple of things I need to consider:

1. Test on different possible input permutation
2. Test on different scale of input size
3. Keep hardware configuration consistent across all the algorithms
4. Major challenge is in implementing sorting algorithm. Because if I implement one and if that happens to be the non-efficient way of implementation it will generate inaccurate result. How would I tackle this?
   Tomorrow if someone comes up with his/her own sorting algorithms how would he/she compare with other sorting algorithm?

Though I am flexible with any programming language but would really appreciate if someone can suggest me some functions available in python.

Comment: When you compare sorting algorithms , you have to do it on large amount of data otherwise you can't see the difference. Use doubling ratio test and try to make a relation between scientific method and results of ratio test.

Comment: All the performances are listed at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @cricket_007 only asymptotic behaviour though

Comment: @Luai Ghunim Thanks! Is there any something similar to doubling ratio test in python as well?

Comment: @Crypto i think you have stopwatch in almost in every language , all you need is stopwatch

Comment: @cricket_007 if you could read question properly, I am not asking about asymptotic behaviour, of course. Also I don't know why did you remove the python tag because I was looking for one such feature available in python. Sorry for the confusion, I should probably edit the question.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim Thanks again! Yeah I got something similar in python https://pypi.python.org/pypi/contexttimer/0.3.1
I wish that will help me

Comment: In python, you would be looking for `timeit`

Comment: Implementing your own sorting algorithm in Python won't be competitive with Python's built-in sort functions, because those are compiled C.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: depending on what you need a sorting algo for, a simple sort like InsertionSort can be the best choice if you need to sort small (like 30 element) arrays.  Even though it's asymptotically worse than MergeSort or other O(n log n) or non-comparison-based O(n) sorts, it can be a good choice because the constant factors are low on real hardware.  Real MergeSort and QuickSort implementations often use InsertionSort for the small 16-element sub-problems instead of recursing all the way down to 1 element.

Comment: @PeterCordes You can examine the behaviour of algorithms by running them on different size of arrays but linearithmic algorithms needs to be run  on large arrays otherwise they will only show worst performance w.r.t Insertion sort.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: Right, but if you *want* to find the fastest small-problem sorting algorithm, then that's what you should test.  If you want to find the fastest general purpose algorithm, then yes you should test a range of sizes.  @ Crypto: design your benchmark to match your use-case as closely as possible.  And make sure to re-randomize your data every iteration, or else branch prediction may perfectly predict everything even for a 20 element sort!

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the explanation and suggestion. How about using https://searchcode.com/file/103094442/rpython/rlib/listsort.py for comparing python build in timsort vs my algorithm ?

Comment: @PeterCordes i agree what you say :)

Comment: @Crypto i added how you can use timer and to see number of compares you can use a counter class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i think you are having trouble what a doubling ratio test is. I know only basics of python so i got this code from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_clock.htm)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time


# measure wall time
t0 = time.time()
procedure() // call from here the main function of your sorting class and as 
                 the (sorting)process ends then it will automatically print 
                 the time taken by a sorting algorithm

print time.time() - t0, "seconds wall time"
```